# Best way to make a scroll top/bottom button

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've made a button in the right-bottom corner of my HTML-page, but I was wondering since it's the first time I've made this, if there is another better way to do this, or if you guys can see anything funky about the way I did this?

This post is mostly to learn how to do things the right way, since I'm a beginner at this.

Thanks for your help.

**Here is my code** --> if you want to GOTO: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mungax/7m6gtuk9/)

```js
var bottomPage = document.getElementById('bottomPage');
var topPage = document.getElementById('topPage');
var lastScrollTop = 0;

bottomPage.addEventListener('click', scrollBottom);
topPage.addEventListener('click', scrollTop);

// element should be replaced with the actual target element on which you have applied scroll, use window in case of no target element.
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ // or element.addEventListener('scroll'....
  var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if (st > lastScrollTop){
    bottomPage.style.display = 'none';
    topPage.style.display = '';
  } else {
    bottomPage.style.display = '';
    topPage.style.display = 'none';
  }
  lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st;
}, false);
function scrollBottom() {
  window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
  bottomPage.style.display = 'none';
  topPage.style.display = '';
}
function scrollTop() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  topPage.style.display = 'none';
  bottomPage.style.display = '';
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 3000px;
  background: white;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #33ccff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);
}

.right-corder-container {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #dddddd79;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none
}

.right-corder-container img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.right-corder-container:hover {
  background: #85858579;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <button class='right-corder-container' id='bottomPage' type='button'><img src='https://i.postimg.cc/87f0hmm2/scroll-down.png'></button>

  <button class='right-corder-container' style='display: none;' id='topPage' type='button'><img src='https://i.postimg.cc/Tp4sL4gj/scroll-up.png'></button>


</body>
```

Comment: I think this question is more suited for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below. I use jQuery to make the code simpler. Also, added `html {scroll-behavior: smooth}` to the CSS to create a smooth scroll.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){

  let btn = $(this)

  setTimeout(function(){
    if(btn.text() == 'GO down'){

        btn.text('GO up');
        btn.attr('href','#top');

    }else{

      btn.text('GO down')
      btn.attr('href','#bottom')

    }
   }, 600);
});
```

```css
html{scroll-behavior: smooth}
.main{height:2000px;background:#f7f7f7}
.btn{position:fixed;right:50px;bottom:50px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="top"></div>
<a class="btn" href="#bottom">GO down</a>
<div class="main"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

I use `setTimeout()` method to give a delay on the changes to the text and attribute `href`, so it gives an effect of change when the page stops scrolling.

Comment: Be aware that `scroll-behavior` also messes with the search function. This can easily be fixed with `:focus-within`. Check out this [detailed explanation](https://css-tricks.com/fixing-smooth-scrolling-with-find-on-page/)

Comment: `scroll-behavior` is currently not supported on Safari. Would be better to use `requestAnimationframe` to animate the actual `scrollTop` position.